# Nitrogen lone pair electrons on 2-acetyl-1-pyrroline

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, molecular-structure

Please consider 2-acetyl-1-pyrroline:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-Acetyl-1-pyrroline

[image: 1-(3,4-dihydro-2H-pyrrol-5-yl)ethan-1-one]

What is the molecular geometry of the nitrogen lone pair?  Is the lone pair oriented in-plane with the ring?  How is this distinct from the orientation carbon-acetyl bond, which should presumably point out-of-plane with the ring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nitrogen lone pair is in plane with the ring because it is in one of the three $sp^2$ hybrid orbitals of N. The other two hybrid orbitals form $\sigma$ bonds to the adjacent carbons, and all three are in plane, with an angle of 120° between them. The $p_z$ orbital of N which is perpendicular to the ring plain forms the $\pi$ bond of the C=N double bond. The acetyl substituent should also lie in plane with the ring because this would allow energetically favorable conjugation between the two double bonds (C=N and C=O).

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  Would the carbon substituent group still lie in-plane with the ring if we replaced the acetyl with something like a methane?

Comment: There would be no conjugation, but the methyl group would still lie in plane because it is smaller, and it does not contain more substituents (only 3 H) which can rotate out of plane and thus significantly affect conformation of the molecule (like in the case of C=O, where the orientation is significant due to the possible conjugation).